# Steganography on PPM images

Tags: beginner, c, image, steganography

I have recently finished a project on stenography on P3 images and just wanted some advice if there was any improvements I could make on my code. I am new to C so not sure if what I am doing is the best practice so just wanting to learn!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

/*Using a Link list as the primary Data Structure */

/*Part A Structures*/

//Create the linked list
typedef struct NODE 
{
char *val;
struct NODE *next;
}NODE;

//Hold the Pixel of the image
typedef struct PIXEL 
{
 int R, G, B;
}PIXEL;

//Hold the PPM Image
typedef struct PPM 
{
char format[2];;
NODE *comments;
int w, h;
int max;
PIXEL * arr;
}PPM;

/**
* function used to deepcopy the linkedlist holding the comments.
* it returns a pointer to a deepcopy of the list passed as a parameter;
*/
//Copy the linked list
//Points to the copy
NODE *copy(NODE *first) 
{
NODE *second = NULL, *previous = NULL;

while (first != NULL) 
{
NODE * temp = (NODE *) malloc(sizeof(NODE));
temp->val = first->val;
temp->next = NULL;

if (second == NULL) 
{
    second = temp;
    previous = temp;
} 
else 
{
    previous->next = temp;
    previous = temp;
}
first = first->next;
}
return second;
}


//Copy the PPM File Returning Pointer
struct PPM * createPPM(PPM *old) 
 {
PPM *new = (PPM*) malloc(sizeof(PPM));

strcpy(new->format, old->format); 
new->comments = copy(old->comments); 

new->h = old->h;
new->w = old->w;
new->max = old->max;

new->arr = (PIXEL *) malloc(old->h * old->w * sizeof(PIXEL));
memcpy(new->arr, old->arr, old->h * old->w * sizeof(PIXEL));

return new;
}

/*Part B */


//Function to read a PPM file and store the structure
struct PPM * getPPM(FILE * fd) 
{
PPM *image = (PPM *) malloc(sizeof(PPM));

fscanf(fd, "%s", image->format);
if (strcmp(image->format, "P3") != 0) 
{
printf("Invalid Image Type");
exit(0);
}
char c = getc(fd);
image->comments = (NODE *) malloc(sizeof(NODE));
NODE *temp = image->comments;
 while ((c = getc(fd)) == '#') 
{
fseek(fd, -1, SEEK_CUR); 
char str[50];
fgets(str, 50, fd);
temp->val = (char *) malloc(strnlen(str, 50));
strcpy(temp->val, str);
temp->val[strlen(temp->val) - 1] = 0;
temp->next = (NODE *) malloc(sizeof(NODE));
temp = temp->next;
temp->next = NULL;
}

fseek(fd, -1, SEEK_CUR);
fscanf(fd, "%d", &image->w);
fscanf(fd, "%d", &image->h);
fscanf(fd, "%d", &image->max);

image->arr = (PIXEL *) malloc(image->h * image->w * sizeof(PIXEL));

int t = 0;
int j = 0;

while (j < image->h * image->w)
{
t = fscanf(fd, "%d", &image->arr[j].R);
t = fscanf(fd, "%d", &image->arr[j].G);
t = fscanf(fd, "%d", &image->arr[j].B);
j = j + 1;
}

return image;
}

//Encode The message into the PPM file
struct PPM * encode(char * text, struct PPM * i) 
{
PPM * str = createPPM(i); 
int random;
srand((unsigned) time(NULL));
int randMax = (i->h * i->w) / (strlen(text)+1);

random = rand() % randMax; 

if(random<1)
{
random = 1; 
}

int k =0;
int j = random;

//Red fields swapped with ASCII int
while (k < strlen(text)) 
{
if(str->arr[j].R == text[k])
{
    j = j+1; // if the values are the same we encode in the next  pixel.
}
else
{
str->arr[j].R = text[k]; 
k = k+1;
j = j + random;
}
}

return str;
}

//Function Decodes the messages comparing the new copy to the original
char * decode(struct PPM * i1, struct PPM * i2) 
{
int i = 0;
int j = 0;

char *str = (char *) malloc(255);

while (i < i1->h * i1->w)
{
if(i1->arr[i].R != i2->arr[i].R)
{
str[j] = i2->arr[i].R;
j = j+1;
}
i = i + 1;
}

str = realloc(str,i);

return str;
}

/**
* function to print the PPM structure
*/
void showPPM(struct PPM * i) 
{
printf("%s\n", i->format); //print format

//print comments
NODE *n = i->comments;
while (n->next != NULL)
{
printf("%s\n", n->val);
n = n->next;
}

//print width, height and max
printf("%d %d\n%d\n", i->w, i->h, i->max);

//print the array containing the pixels
int j;
for (j = 0; j < i->h * i->w; ++j) 
{
printf("%d %d %d\n", i->arr[j].R, i->arr[j].G, i->arr[j].B);
}

return;
}

int main (int argc, char ** argv)
{

if(argc != 3 && argc != 4)
{ 
printf("Encode 3 arguments, Decode 4\n");
exit(0);
}

else if(argc ==3)
{   
if(strncmp(argv[1], "e",1) != 0)
{ 
    printf("non valid commands %s for %d arguments\n", argv[1], argc);
    exit(0);
}

FILE * f = fopen(argv[2], "r");
PPM * ppm1 = getPPM(f);
fclose(f);
char * toEnc =(char*) malloc(255 * sizeof(char));
fgets (toEnc, 255, stdin);
PPM * encoded = encode(toEnc, ppm1);
showPPM(encoded);
}

else
{
if(strncmp(argv[1], "d",1) != 0)
{
    printf("non valid commands %s for %d arguments\n", argv[1], argc);
    exit(0);    
}
FILE * file1 = fopen(argv[2], "r");
FILE * file2 = fopen(argv[3], "r");
PPM * ppm1 = getPPM(file1);
PPM * ppm2 = getPPM(file2);
char * dec = decode(ppm1, ppm2);
printf("%s", dec); 
}

}
```

Comment: Is this how you really didn't indent your code? (The easiest way to post code is to paste it, highlight it, and press Ctrl-K to mark it as a code block.)

Answer (score 1):

It is best to separate the definition of a `struct` from the definition of a `typedef`

So this:

```
typedef struct NODE
{
    char *val;
    struct NODE *next;
}NODE;
```

would be better written as:

```
struct NODE
{
    char *val;
    struct NODE *next;
};

typedef struct NODE NODE;
```

Similar considerations apply to `PIXEL` and `PPM` for readability and ease of understanding:

1. Separate code blocks (`for`, `if`, `else`, `while`, `do...while`, `switch`, `case`, `default`) via a blank line.
2. Separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent)
3. Consistently indent the code:

   - Indent after every opening brace '{'
   - Unindent before every closing brace '}'
   - Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces as that is wide enough to be visible even with variable width fonts

For assureance that a call to a system function was successful, check the returned value: when calling: `malloc()`, `fscanf()`, `realloc()`m, `fopen()`, `fseek()` to avoid memory leaks, for each call to a heap memory allocation function (slightly more complicated for `realloc()`, there needs to be a call to `free()` for that same memory pointer.

The function `srand()` should only be called ONCE in the whole program. Suggest calling `srand()` very early in the `main()` function.

When exiting the program due to an error, do not use a return value of `0` as that is used to indicate success. Suggest using `EXIT_FAILURE` (defined in the `stdlib.h` header fileno. It is considered best to (when making a comparison using the `==` operator) to place the literal on the left, so a keypunch error like typing `=` rather than `==` will be be caught by the compiler (`else if( 3 == argc )`).

When outputting an error message, it should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`, so use either:

```
fprintf( stderr, "...");
```

or if due to a system function use:

```
perror "..." );
```

`perror()` will also output the text from the OS as to why the OS thinks the error occurred.

The memory allocation functions (`malloc`, `realloc`, `calloc`) return a pointer with type `void*`, so can be assigned to any other pointer. Casting the returned value just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.

PPM images have to have a multiple of 4 bytes on each row, so there is often some 'dummy' bytes at the end of each row, The posted code is failing to allow for that condition.

The function `getc()` returns an `int`, not a `char` and the returned value should always be checked for `EOF`.

When compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings. (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`. I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu11`).

Variable and parameter names should indicate `content` or `usage` (or better, both). Parameter names like `i` are meaningless, even in the current context

Regarding this line:

```
temp->val = (char *) malloc(strnlen(str, 50));
```

The function `strnlen()` will not allow enough room for the trailing NUL byte, so the line should be:

```
temp->val = malloc(strnlen(str, 50)+1);
```

This line:

```
temp->val[strlen(temp->val) - 1] = 0;
```

will chop off the last character of the string, and this line is not needed at all because the prior call to `strcpy()` will include a trailing NUL byte.

Regarding this field in the struct PPM:

```
char format[2];;
```

The method of setting that field will include a trailing NUL byte and perhaps even a newline (which the code should be overlaying the newline with a NUL char) so the line should be: (including removing the extra `;`)

```
char format[3];
```

There are plenty more problems but the above should get you started.

```
#endif





#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

/*Using a Link list as the primary Data Structure */

/*Part A Structures*/

//Create the linked list
struct NODE
{
    char *val;
    struct NODE *next;
};
typedef struct NODE NODE;

//Hold the Pixel of the image
struct PIXEL
{
    int R;
    int G;
    int B;
};
typedef struct PIXEL PIXEL;

//Hold the PPM Image
struct PPM
{
    char format[2];;
    NODE *comments;
    int w, h;
    int max;
    PIXEL * arr;
};
typedef struct PPM PPM;


#if 0
The following function does not seem to actually perform a deep copy,
suggest looking carefully at the logic.
#endif

/**
* function used to deepcopy the linkedlist holding the comments.
* it returns a pointer to a deepcopy of the list passed as a parameter;
*/
//Copy the linked list
//Points to the copy
NODE *copy(NODE *first)
{
    NODE *second = NULL;
    NODE *previous = NULL;

    while (first != NULL)
    {
        NODE * temp = malloc(sizeof(NODE));
        if( !temp )
        {
            perror( "malloc failed" );
            // need logic here to pass all heap pointers to 'free()'
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, malloc successful

        temp->val = first->val;
        temp->next = NULL;

        if (second == NULL)
        {
            second = temp;
            previous = temp;
        }

        else
        {
            previous->next = temp;
            previous = temp;
        }

        first = first->next;
    }
    return second;
} // end function: copy
```

Comment: Can you cite a reference for the very first line of your answer? Please explain why it is better to separate the typedef from the struct declaration. I might be able to upvote the answer if you explain.

Comment: when working with a debugger, if the struct has a 'tag' name, then the debugger can display the individual fields of the struct.  In general, it is a poor programming practice (often abused) to combine the 'typedef' with the struct definition.  Such action obscures the layout of the struct and makes the struct definition un-available for any other usage.